# Sorting a list to be assigned to Combobox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.5, generic-list

I have a list of string lets say

```
List<string> mia = new list<string>;
```

and i am adding data to it from a database

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT xyz FROM table",sqlConnection1))
{
     sqlConnection1.Open();
     using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
     {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
               mia.Add(reader["xyz"].ToString());
          }

     }
     sqlConnection1.Close();                     
}
```

data is successfully added to it.

```
combobox.ItemsSource =mia;
```

even that works fine

But when i try to do

```
comboOpthol.ItemsSource =mia.Sort();
```

intellisense throws error Can not implicitly convert type "void" to `System.collections.IEnumerable`. Why this error is coming. My list have all data then why show it void?
Is there something wrong with way list is defined list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the `Sort()` method does not have a return value (it sorts the list in place and returns `void`). You need to sort first and then assign the list to the item source:

```
mia.Sort();
comboOpthol.ItemsSource = mia;
```

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>.Sort` does not return a new list, it sorts the existing one.

```
mia.Sort();
comboOpthol.ItemsSource = mia;
```

Consider sorting the results at the database level with `ORDER BY`.

You've tagged your question with `linq` which leads me to believe you think `List<T>.Sort()` is linq. It is not, it's a method of `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You should sort it before setting it as source:

```
mia.Sort();
comboOpthol.ItemsSource =mia;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because .Sort() does not return a "new" sorted list. It just sorts the excisting one.

Just do

```
mia.Sort();
comboOpthol.ItemsSource = mia;
```